# Traer datos de una base de datos para consulta general

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, mvc, sql-server-2014, parametros

Espero me pueda apoyar con el siguiente problema en MVC C#

Requiero traer los datos en un Grid de mi base de datos que tengo como procedimiento almacenado..

cuando ejecuto en paso de parametros F10...

El controlador pasa a la clase CRUDColonia y la Clase CRUDColonia regresa al controlador y el controlador a la vista

pero nunca la clase CRUDColonia pasa por la Clase Colonia por lo tanto siempre me trae datos nullos..

Que puedo hacer para que el CRUDColonia traiga los datos que estan en la clase colonia?

Utilizo SQLServer 2014 y VS2019 MVC C#

Gracias de antemano!

Tengo mi modelo:

```
public class ModelColonia
{

    public int Id_colonia { get; set; }
    public string Colonia { get; set; }

    public object Error_col { get; set; }


}
```

Este es mi Namespace Datos y mi class se llama Colonia

```
public List<Models.ModelColonia> Obtener(List<SqlParameter> filtros = null)
    {
        list = new List<Models.ModelColonia>();

        using (oCon = new SqlServer())
        {

            if (filtros != null)

                foreach (SqlParameter p in filtros)
                {
                    oCon.addParameter(p);
                }
            try
            {
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader drInfo = oCon.executeReader("dbo.proc_get" + this.GetType().Name))
                {
                    while (drInfo.Read())
                    {
                        obj = new Models.ModelColonia()
                        {

                            Id_colonia = Convert.ToInt32(drInfo["id_colonia"]),
                            Colonia = (drInfo["colonia"]).ToString()

                        };

                        list.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                _errorMensaje = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
```

A continuacion tengo la class CRUDColonia

private int totalRegistros = 0;

```
    public List<ModelColonia> GetObtener(Int32? idcol, String nombre, int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
    {
        Datos.Colonia obj = new Datos.Colonia();
        List<ModelColonia> listaObjs = new List<ModelColonia>();
        List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> campos = new List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>();
        campos.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id_colonia", idcol));
        campos.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@colonia", nombre));

        listaObjs = obj.Obtener(campos);
        totalRegistros = listaObjs.Count();

        return listaObjs;
    }
```

posteriormente tengo el controlador

```
namespace SistemaMc.Controllers
```

{
    public class ColoniaController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Colonia

```
    List<ModelColonia> oCamposColonia = new List<ModelColonia>();
    CRUD.CRUDColonia dblayer = new CRUD.CRUDColonia();

     public ActionResult Obtener ()
    {


        CRUDColonia Colobt  = new CRUDColonia();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(Colobt.GetObtener(null, null, 0,0));

    }

 }
```

}

La vista:

```html
@model IEnumerable<SistemaMc.Models.ModelColonia>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Obtener";
   // Layout = "~/Views/Colonia.cshtml";
}

<h2>Obtener</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Employee", "AddEmployee")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id_colonia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Colonia)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id_colonia)
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Colonia)
            </td>
          
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmpDetails", new { id = item.Id_colonia }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmp", new { id = item.Colonia }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" })
            </td>
        </tr>



    }
</table>
```

Comment: Un par de observaciones: en tu controller, tienes Colobt.GetObtener, que al parecer no existe. Si se trata del método "Obtener", entonces, ese ya devuelve una lista, no tienes por qué llamar tantas veces a .ToList(). Por qué no pones el nombre completo del procedimiento en el executeReader(), en lugar de concatenar? Prueba también verificar si existe alguna excepción. El catch la atrapa, pero no tienes cómo mostrar ese código.

Comment: Intenta también utilizar los tags correcto. [sqlServer] y [aspnet-mvc] hubiesen sido más adecuadas

Comment: El metodo Obtener no tiene ningun return.. no estas teniendo un error informado por Visual Studio ahi???

Comment: Amigos gracias por responder.. y por las observaciones corregui el codigo pero aun asi sigue sin traerme los datos de mi procedimiento almacenado... Por qué no pones el nombre completo del procedimiento en el executeReader().. de hecho lo tengo de la misma manera en el de insertar y si me funciona.... Sigo al pendiente de sus consejos y de su ayudas para poder lograr traer los datos a mi grid

Comment: @gbianchi es correcto, corregui el código pero sigue sin traerme los datos de mi grid.. que me aconsejas o donde puedo seguir teniendo el error

Comment: Ni idea, hay que rastrear en el codigo donde se pierden tus datos

Comment: lo hice con F10.. el problema es que en la clase CRUDColonia hasta ahi sigue trayendo datos nulos y de ahi debería de pasar a la clase Colonia.. pero no pasa.. la clase CRUDColonia se regresa al Controlador y el controlador a la vista...

Comment: En el  catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    _errorMensaje = ex.Message.ToString();
                }                                                                                                                               este error es el que me genera                                                                          {"La función o el procedimiento proc_getCOLONIA tiene demasiados argumentos."}

Comment: ya lo resolvi.. era en mi procedimiento almacenado mi error.. gracias de antemano! Saludos..